# How to prevent img resize in a div

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have some images in a slider and I'm trying to prevent them from automatically resizing in the same ratio when I resize my browser. What I'm trying to achieve is that the image stays with the same height and with a slightly different width until the browser reaches a breaking point via @media queries.
It's exactly what http://www.worldwildlife.org/ achieved with its slider when you resize the browser.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
         <li><img src="../Img/001.jpg" alt="foto" /></li>
         <li><img src="../Img/002.jpg" alt="foto2"/></li>
         <li><img src="../Img/003.jpg" alt="foto3"/></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#fondo3 {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left:0;
    top:10%;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width:auto;
}

.rslides {
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.rslides img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Your link achieved that by using ``position: absolute; margin-left: -/*half width of image*/; left: 50%;`` for the ``img``

Answer (score 0):

you need to use css media queries and resize the img at x width bit like this

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

     img {
       width:300px
      }
  }

@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
          img {
       width:600px
      }
  }
```

here's a link to the [css](http://www.worldwildlife.org/assets/application-0fe304f522a309efd41c1d410b4a33ff.css) used by the site search for @media

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is to make the image resize proportionately keeping its aspect ratio intact which is possible by making all the elements responsive to the browser resize.

Check out my example:

http://codingclown.com/html5-fully-responsive-carousel-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

one way is to set an image as the background of a `div`, instead of using an `img` tag

[see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teq57r4n/)

resize the result box and see how it changes